# How can I write emit even to tell parent is icon is clicked in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am write input element with icon to show/hide password, how can I write event emit in v-icon to tell parent component that icon is click
Here is my child component BaseInputPassword

```
        <div class="label">
      {{ labelName }} <span v-if="required" class="required">※</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input_password">
           <input
                :type="type ? 'password' : 'text'"
                :placeholder="placeholder"
              />
           <v-icon @click="type =! type">{{ type ? "mdi-eye-off" : "mdi-eye" }}</v-icon>
    </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["labelName", "placeholder", "required", "type" ],
  data() {
    return {  
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue($event) {
      this.$emit("input", $event);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

*****Here is my parent component, im using three child component*****

```
      <div class="input_area">
          <BlockInputPassword  labelName="現在のパスワード" required="true" :type="show1" v-model="password" ></BlockInputPassword>
          <BlockInputPassword labelName="現在のパスワード" required="true" :type="show2"  v-model="password" ></BlockInputPassword>
          <BlockInputPassword labelName="新しいパスワードの確認" required="true" :type="show3" v-model="password"></BlockInputPassword>
         </div>
      </div>
         <div class="footer">
             <router-link to=""
          ><div class="btn_login btn_simple">
            キャンセル
          </div></router-link>
             <router-link to=""
          ><div class="btn_login btn_simple status_color_4">
            変更
          </div></router-link>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import BlockInputPassword from "../components/common/BlockInputPassword"
export default {
  components: {
    BlockInputPassword,
  },
  name: "PasswordChange",
  data() {
    return {
         password: '',
         show1: false,
         show2: false,
         show3: false,
        };
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

have you child component `v-icon` emit a custom event

```
<v-icon @click="$emit('icon-clicked')">
```

then from the parent component

```
<div class="input_area">
    <BlockInputPassword @icon-click="doSomething" ...></BlockInputPassword>
    ...
</div>
```